How to make <h1></h1> to <h2></h2> in one go in VS code?
How can I change <h1></h1> to <h2></h2> in one go in V.S code? I saw in freecodecamp where the person leading the tutorial just clicked on <h1> and changed it to <h2> and the </h1> automatically changed to </h2>
I have to manually change <h1></h1> to <h2></h2>, so how can I change it automatically?
In VS Code, is it a keyboard shortcut? like shift alt and down arrow?

not sure about just clicking. but u can use Ctrl + Shift + P (or Cmd + Shift + P on macOS) to open the Command Palette.
Type Emmet: Update Tag and select it.
Type the new tag name (h2) and press Enter. This will change both the opening and closing tags automatically.

Under the Selection menu there should be an option for Select All Occurrences with a hint for the relevant keyboard shortcut. Use that and change the tag by typing the new one

You can use Find and replace text in Visual Studio.

Emmet: Update Tag command, you can create a key binding that changes the current tag to h2

VS Code has a built in setting that lets you edit opening and closing tags for HTML, XML, and JSX files at the same time. It is not on by default, but the setting is called Editor: Linked Editing. This will make it so that changes to the opening or closing tag are linked together.
Here's an article that explains this feature, along with many other common use cases that people don't always realize are built into VS Code, and don't require an extension (not that there is anything wrong with extensions): VS Code - You don't need that extension

It does not change by clicking, but you can use the following methods

Manual Replacement with Regular Expressions:
Find: 
Replace: 
Use Regular Expressions: If you want to replace all occurrences in a file, enable the regular expression option and use //g for the find and  for the replace.
Multi-Cursor Editing:
While not a direct conversion, you can use VS Code's multi-cursor editing to efficiently change multiple  tags to  simultaneously.

Hold Ctrl (or Cmd on Mac) and click on the opening  tags you want to change.
Type h2 to replace all selected  with .

The fastest way is to use replace all.

Press Ctrl + h. This will open the replace prompt at the top right corner.
Search for h1 and let it replace with h2
Use the replace all button or press Ctrl + Alt + Enter


